# Error when setting up VSTS linux build agent

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup a linux build agent on a ubuntu VM running in azure. I followed the instructions in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/08/19/build-push-and-run-docker-images-with-visual-studio-team-services/) article

all good until i run the command to configure the agent 
**./config.sh**

and getting the below error:-

**Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500**

Anyone faced this issue before?
Also note that I followed all the pre-requisites for the VSTS Linux agent